# Sum of squares using variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

I am trying to find the sum of squares using variadic templates. The input parameters are the numbers whose sum of squares need to be calculated. Ex: `foo(2, 3, 4)` should return a value of `27` (which is `2+(9+16)`). My template function looks as follows:

```
template<typename T>
T foo(T args)
{
    return args*args;
}

template <typename T, typename... A>
T foo(T first, A... args)
{
    return first+foo(pow(args,2)...);
}
```

However the result of this function seems to be 261 which was not what I expected.

Comment: 27 is wrong already... Why not 4+9+16?

Comment: @VadimKotov - the C++11 tag is correct because the question is about variadic-templates, introduced in C++ in the C++11 version; but (IMHO) also C++ is correct because it's the language where C++11 is the version; moreover: until 10 March 2018 in the C++11 tag description was written "Please tag questions about C++11 with the `c++` tag, along with the `c++11` tag".

Comment: @max66 That's right. But before that there were 2 version tags on this question: [tag:c++11] and [tag:c++14]

Comment: @VadimKotov - Sorry; I didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: 2 + 9 + 256 = 267

Let's expand this:

```
foo(2, 3, 4) => 2 + foo(pow(args, 2)...)
             => 2 + foo(pow(3, 2), pow(4, 2))
             => 2 + foo(9, 16)
             => 2 + (9 + foo(16))
             => 2 + (9 + 16 * 16)
             => 267
Hello world!
```

If you want to do it right, don't `pow()` one value multiple times:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(T arg)
{
    return arg * arg;
}

template <typename T, typename... A>
T foo(T first, A... args)
{
    return first * first + foo(args...);
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ or pow(first, 2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to find the sum of squares using variadic templates. The input parameters are the numbers whose sum of squares need to be calculated. Ex: foo(2, 3, 4) should return a value of 27 (which is 2+(9+16))

It's too late to play?

Anyway, if you want to find the sum of squares, `foo(2, 3, 4)` should return `4+9+16 = 29`, not `27`.

I propose a not-recursive function, using the power of the comma operator in initialization of a unused integer array

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
T foo (T const & t, Ts const & ... ts)
 {
   using unused = int[];

   T  ret { t*t };

   (void)unused { 0, (ret += ts*ts, 0)... };

   return ret;
 }
```

From

```
std::cout << foo(2, 3, 4) << std::endl;
```

you get `29`

If you can use C++17, you can use template folding and `foo()` simply become

```
template <typename ... Ts>
auto foo (Ts const & ... ts)
 { return ( (ts*ts) + ... ); }
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the result you're expecting in your description, you would need to capture "first" in one function and recurse with a separate like this:

```
template<typename T>
T bar(T first) {
    return first*first;
}    

template<typename T, typename... A>
T bar(T first, A... args) {
    return bar(first) + bar(args...);
}    

template<typename T, typename... A>
T foo(T first, A... args) {
    return first + bar(args...);
}
```

If instead, you want to square each parameter in your function and sum them, the following should do:

```
template<typename T>
T foo(T first) {
    return first*first;
}

template<typename T, typename... A>
T foo(T first, A... args) {
    return foo(first) + foo(args...);
}
```